# Import variables from component sass in Material 2.0.0-beta.3

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Since upgrading from angular-material `2.0.0-beta.2` to `2.0.0-beta.3` we cannot 'deep import' because

> Deep imports have always been an anti-pattern, but our previous package structure inadvertently allowed them [(source)](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta3-cesium-cephalopod-2017-04-07)

Now using `2.0.0-beta.3` is there a way to reference those internal variables? For example, I could previously use this sass to style a component to match the height of `md-toolbar`:

```scss
@import '~@angular/material/toolbar/toolbar';

.foo {
  height: $mat-toolbar-height-desktop;
  width: $mat-toolbar-height-desktop;
}
```